# Can I use a CNAME record (only) to redirect my domain without an A-record in DDNS situation?

Tags: dynamic, dns, cname

I think I understand the difference between the two and when to use CNAME to redirect normally, but the other questions/answers don't answer my specific scenario which is:

I cannot get a static IP for my host at home, so forced to use DDNS. Let's say I have mydomain.net that I want to point to mydomain.ddns.net. I put a CNAME record in my DNS provider as follows:

CNAME *.mydomain.net mydomain.ddns.net

I use www and ftp hence the wildcard.

I do not have an A-record, since this would only work temporarily until my IP changes again, so the CNAME record is the only one.  I have the No-IP tool running, so mydomain.ddns.net does get updated whenever it changes, and this works perfectly.

When I try to ping mydomain.net, it can't find the host, so DNS isn't working and therefore I suspect something wrong with my CNAME entry.  I suspect it's because I don't have an A-Record, but can't find anywhere to confirm this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `mydomain.net` will usually not match `*.mydomain.net`. What happens if you try `www.mydomain.net`?

Comment: You're right. It could not resolve host for anything unless the A-record existed. Didn't matter though, as I figured out how to use the CloudFlare API via cmd script. Works a treat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`*.example.net` will not catch `example.net`. However, as you mention if you ping `www.example.net` it will hit the CNAME.

Unfortunately you can't have a CNAME on `example.net` because CNAME's are not allowed to co-exist with any other record types, and for `example.net` you will at the very least have records of the type NS (that specifies your nameservers).

One way to get around this, is instead of using ddns.net is to use a provider that has an API, and update the A record for `example.net` directly. One such provider could be [Cloudflare](https://www.cloudflare.com/) that does DNS hosting for free. There are [plenty](https://scotthelme.co.uk/replacing-dyndns-cloudflare-ddns/) of [guides](https://johnpili.com/use-cloudflare-as-dynamic-dns/) on how to use them as Dynamic DNS.

Answer (score 1):

After the inspiration from @colde and a bit of work I wanted to share my batch script that implements his answer.

It is executed by Task Scheduler every 10 minutes, first checks if there is an internet connection, and if so, checks if my public IP changed, and only if so, update the cloudflare DNS via their API.

I've anonymized my personal identifiers and API url, obviously you'd need to change those.

```
@echo off
cls
setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
set logFile=.\UpdatePublicIP.log
call :log "--- SCRIPT STARTED ---"
goto TestInternet

:log
echo [!date! !time!] %~1
echo [!date! !time!] %~1 >>%logFile%
exit /b 0

:TestInternet
REM First test for internet connectivity.
call :log "Detecting internet."
PING -n 1 8.8.8.8|find "Reply from " >NUL
IF NOT ERRORLEVEL 1 goto :CheckPublicIP
IF     ERRORLEVEL 1 goto :NoInternet

:NoInternet
call :log "No internet, nothing to do."
goto End

:CheckPublicIP
call :log "Detecting public IP."
for /f %%A in (
  'powershell -command "(Invoke-Webrequest "http://api.ipify.org").content"'
) do (
      set TempPublicIP=%%A
     )
call :log "Current Public IP: %TempPublicIP%"
if not "%TempPublicIP%"=="%PublicIP%" (
    call :log "Saved IP [%PublicIP%] different to current [%TempPublicIP%] IP, updating saved PublicIP."
    REM Note: setx saves env var but only available in future cmd windows, not current one.
    setx PublicIP %TempPublicIP% >nul
    goto UpdateDNS
    ) else (
            call :log "Current IP = saved IP, nothing to do."
           )
goto End

:UpdateDNS
call :log "Updating CloudFlare DNS record to [%TempPublicIP%]."
curl -X PUT "https://api.cloudflare.com/client/v4/zones/12345abcde12345abcde12345abcde12/dns_records/1234567890qwertyuiop0987654321ab" -H "X-Auth-Email: yourusername@hotmail.com" -H "X-Auth-Key:a123b4567c8defghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz123" -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data "{\"type\":\"A\",\"name\":\"yourdomainname.net\",\"content\":\"%TempPublicIP%\"}"|findstr.exe modified_on >nul
REM Can't use "success":true due to the quote. Assuming the string "modified_on" occurs on success only.
IF NOT ERRORLEVEL 1 goto :CloudFlareSuccess
IF     ERRORLEVEL 1 goto :CloudFlareError
goto End

:CloudFlareSuccess
call :log "CloudFlare DNS update succeeded.
goto End

:CloudFlareError
call :log "CloudFlare DNS update failed.
goto End

:End
call :log "--- SCRIPT FINISHED ---"
```